# Prevent loaded Javascript file from executing after running another function

Tags: javascript, html

```js
// java1.js
////////////////////////

const activities = [];
var json = {
  "Tasks": [{
    "Subject": "Hello"
  }, {
    "Subject": "Bonjour"
  }, ]
}
var obj = json.Tasks;

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  activitySub = (obj[i].Subject);
  activities.push({
    activitySub
  })
}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(activities)));

const html = activities.map(obj => {
  let item = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
  item = item.replace('{sub}', obj.activitySub);
  return item;
});
document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = html.join('');

// java2.js
////////////////////////

function java2()
{
const activities = [];
var json = {
  "Tasks": [{
    "Subject": "Hello"
  }, {
    "Subject": "Hallo"
  }, ]
}
var obj = json.Tasks;

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  activitySub = (obj[i].Subject);
  activities.push({
    activitySub
  })
}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(activities)));

const html = activities.map(obj => {
  let item = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
  item = item.replace('{sub}', obj.activitySub);
  return item;
});
document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = html.join('');
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">
      Link to java2.js
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <template id="template">
    <p class id="java2" onclick="javascript: $.getScript('java2.js' , function (){ web() ; } );" />{sub}
  </template>
</ul>
```

So I have 3 files:

```
web.html
java1.js
java2.js
```

I'm loading java1.js in the html. When this runs it writes into web.html with a list of items.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../java1.js"></script>
```

Then I have jQuery that executes a function in java2.js. What this is supposed to do is populate the html with a different list of items. This code does work because if I load it instead of java1.js, I get a different list.

```
<a href="#" id ="web" onclick="javascript: $.getScript('java2.js' , function (){ web() ; } );" />
```

Where I'm having a tough time is, even though java2.js is executing successfully, it doesn't refresh the data in the html. That seems to make sense so I added this to java2.js

```
window.location = window.location
```

and now it does refresh the html but, it reloads java1.js since it loads when the html loads and I'm back to having the original list.

So finally my question is, what's the best way to execute java2.js without loading java1.js data back into the html?
Thanks you much!

Comment: Please show your code, ideally using the <> icon to insert it straight into this page, as an edit to your question.

Comment: Will do. It's lot more than I can post here. Let me try to trim it down to an example.

Comment: Yes, trimming is important. More: [mre]

Comment: I really tried to get it down and still get my point across. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data in `localStorage` once the data has been loaded, and then check for that data in `localStorage` before updating the lists:

Java 1:

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem("dataLoaded")) {
  lists = []; // set the initial values
}
```

Java 2:

```js
lists = []; // set new values
localStorage.setItem("dataLoaded", true);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This took care of it. I appreciate it, Rojo!